# What is the map returned by System.getenv() and how the values are set in this map?

Tags: java, properties

I have the following statements in my (java) code.

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
String filePath = env.get("CSV_FILEPATH");
```

But I am not sure how the value of that key `"CSV_FILEPATH"` is being set?
There is not a property file I can find.

My question is what are the possible ways to set that value?

I have checked system variables in Linux.

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
String filePath = env.get("CSV_FILEPATH");
```

Comment: Those are basically the variables that you can see with `printenv` . One way of adding such a variable, is exporting it in the `.bashrc` located in the home directory of the current user.

Comment: Any feasible reason to pass file path by system environment variable and not by properties file, or command line argument?

Comment: @Socowi : Indeed, but the question was asked about system variables in Linux, and how to populate them.